# Calculating with numbers below zero

Tags: java, string

Please excuse me if this question is really obvious but i've tried everything.

I am trying to make a calculator that calculates the percentage of a number.

But it keeps outputting a 0 for the outputs when I use this code :

```
import java.io.*;

class pCalc {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;
          BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(istream) ;

          System.out.println("Hello...");

          try {
               System.out.println("Please Enter In The Percentage You Want To Find (e.g 25): ");
               String rpercent = bufRead.readLine();

               System.out.println("Please Enter In The Number You Wish To Find The Percentage Of (e.g 200): ");
               String rnumber = bufRead.readLine();


               int repercent = Integer.parseInt(rpercent);
               int number = Integer.parseInt(rnumber);
               int percent = repercent / 100;

               int awnswer = number * percent ;

               System.out.println("Percent is: " + percent);
               System.out.println("Awnswer is: " + awnswer);
          }
          catch (IOException err) {
               System.out.println("Error reading line");
          }
          catch(NumberFormatException err) {
               System.out.println("Error Converting Number");
          }         
     }
}
```

Comment: Follow good programming practice.. Declare all variables at begining.

Comment: Steve McConnel in Code complete said that variables dont have to be declared at the begenning =)

Comment: @SachinMhetre Declaring vars at the top has not only never been the recommended practice in Java; it is not recommended even in ANSI C.

Comment: Agree with denis and marko. Only declare the var when you start need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is natural number (or it's negative... blah, **`int` is Integer**), it can't be anything between 0 or 1. You must use `float` or `double` if you want to see something like `0,25`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies here:

```
       int repercent = Integer.parseInt(rpercent);
       int number = Integer.parseInt(rnumber);
       int percent = repercent / 100;
```

The result of an integer division will eventually be an integer, so, for instance if the calculation yields `0.2` it will be changed to `0`.

Doing something like so should fix it:

```
   double repercent = Double.parseDouble(rpercent);
   double number = Double.parseDouble(rnumber);
   double percent = repercent / 100.0;
```

Comment: +1. And just want to comment that Double.valueOf() and Integer.valueOf() are better than Integer.parseInt() and Double.parseDouble().

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float` instead of `int`

```
float repercent = Float.parseFloat(rpercent);
float number = Float.parseFloat(rnumber);
float percent = repercent / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int percent = repercent / 100;` won't work. [Use](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=261) the `float` or `double` data-types.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your code a bit. The main problem, as others have noted, is premature integer division by 100. Removed exception handling as it is superfluous and masks the full stacktrace that would have been printed by the default exception handler.

```
package test;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    final BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;
    System.out.println("Hello...");
    System.out.println("Please Enter In The Percentage You Want To Find (e.g 25): ");
    final int percent = parseInt(bufRead.readLine());
    System.out.println(
        "Please Enter In The Number You Wish To Find The Percentage Of (e.g 200): ");
    final int number = parseInt(bufRead.readLine());
    final int answer = number * percent / 100; // or use a floating-point type here
    System.out.println("Percent is: " + percent);
    System.out.println("Answer is: " + answer);
  }
}
```